# Long/Short in a specific zone on Pine

Tags: boolean, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a strategy in place where it should buy/sell in between 2 levels when the price falls/rises into it.

When I implement it into the strategy it is coming up with the error:

'Cannot call 'operator <' with argument "expr0' = 'call 'operator <' (series bool)'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected."

Heres the code:

```
if (not na(k) and not na(d))
    //code to define if k is in overbought zone and k crossover d of more than 2 and ema is uptrend and enter a long trade 
    if (co and k < OverSold and is_uptrend and ((k - d) > 2 ) and (U15 < realC < U3))
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
    //code to define if k is in oversold zone and k crossunder d is more than 2 and ema in downtrend and enters a short trade
    if (cu and k > OverBought and is_downtrend and  ((d - k) > 2) and (L15 > realC > L3))
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="Short")
```

The 'zones' are U15 < realC < U3 and L15 > realC > L3

I have previously stated what U15, realC, U3, L15, L3 are so i'm not sure if what I have coded makes this a bool.

Answer (score 0):

`(U15 < realC < U3)` is not a valid syntax.

You should write it as `((U15 < realC) and (realC < U3))`